# How do I stop VS c++ compiler from deleting my functions?

Tags: compiler-errors

How to prevent VS c++ compiler from deletion my functions.

I have various classes I put on the heap.  When I new them, the new operator function checks the value of a static int.  If it is zero, it calls malloc, saves the malloc return, sets the static to non-zero and returns the address malloc returned.  If the static is non-zero when new is called it just returns the stored address.

I've been doing this since I learned C++ 25 years ago until versions of VS 19 and later got stupid.  Now, I get an error saying the function was deleted. Is there something I can do about this?  Should I try another brand of compiler?